How to use JOptionPane?
I'm learning Java and in one of my exercise I have to do a logging frame which displays warning after push cancel button, before typing id or password.
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Authenticator {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ID:");
        String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("PASSWORD:");

        if (
                username != null && password != null &&
                        (
                                (username.equalsIgnoreCase("bburd") && password.equalsIgnoreCase("whale")) ||
                                (username.equalsIgnoreCase("hritter") && password.equalsIgnoreCase("preakston")) ||
                                (username.equalsIgnoreCase("epiekos") && password.equalsIgnoreCase("simplus"))
    )
        )
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU'RE IN");
        } else {
            Object[] options = { "OK", "CANCEL" };
            JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "NO INFORMATION", "WARNING",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                    null, options, options[0]);
        }
    }
} 

I've try to use an JOptionPane class but the warning doesn't appears after clicking the button. It appears in the end of program.

You might want to start slowly and see what happens when you press cancel (very likely the returned value is null). Then react to that immediately instead of first asking for both id and password and then checking both together. And btw, the pw checks might be simpler if you'd use a map of username -> password and then use a get(username) to see whether the user exists (null means there is no pw for that user) and then compare that pw to whatever the user entered.

what do you mean "it appears in the end"? do you get the 'YOU'RE IN' or the 'NO INFORMATION' messages or do you get nothing?

posted code seems to handle Cancel the same as invalid username/password, intentional? Why have "OK", "CANCEL" options for the warning? Not sure if I did understand the question: code is asking for password even if the user selected Cancel instead of entering the username, that is, it should not ask for password if first dialog is closed with Cancel?

I've copy a code for warning from API I ain't even change it and - yes if the user has not enter username it shouldn't ask for an password

then you can add an if after reading the username before asking for the password

The issue you're encountering is because the code to display the warning message is executing after the input dialog for the password. To display the warning message before entering the password, you should move the code for displaying the warning message to the appropriate location.
Here's the modified version of your code where the warning message is displayed before asking for the password:
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Authenticator {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ID:");

        // Check if username is null or empty
        if (username == null || username.isEmpty()) {
            // Display warning message if username is null or empty
            Object[] options = { "OK", "CANCEL" };
            JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "NO INFORMATION", "WARNING",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                    null, options, options[0]);
        } else {
            // Continue asking for password if username is provided
            String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("PASSWORD:");

            if (
                    password != null &&
                    (
                            (username.equalsIgnoreCase("bburd") && password.equalsIgnoreCase("whale")) ||
                            (username.equalsIgnoreCase("hritter") && password.equalsIgnoreCase("preakston")) ||
                            (username.equalsIgnoreCase("epiekos") && password.equalsIgnoreCase("simplus"))
                    )
            ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU'RE IN");
            } else {
                Object[] options = { "OK", "CANCEL" };
                JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "NO INFORMATION", "WARNING",
                        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                        null, options, options[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}

this should work

Great. It works. Thanks for your help. If there's a solution to continue logging after clickig "OK" in warning frame?

Should I use an another if statement?
Something like this?
if (options = "OK") {
return;
}
I know it doesn't work. How to reference to click "OK" ?
